# Adding Upload functionality to Strapi CMS version 3.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, content-management-system, strapi

I am using Strapi CMS as I am new to it so I am trying to add an image upload feature in already created Admin panel by Strapi.

I have found this

https://github.com/strapi/strapi-generate-upload

but I can't able to implement that because there is not much information and since it using version 1.x so I am not sure if it will work with 3.x or not.

I am just stuck with it and I don't know how to solve it.
So I request the expert to please suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The Upload feature is currently in active development: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/ROADMAP.md / https://strapi.io/vote.

Comment: Thanks, Pierre, I have put my vote for it but could you please let me know is there any alternate or way through which I can do the uploading feature.